# iis 10 on Server 2016. Redirection Why?

Tags: iis, redirection

I have this issue with a newly created site in IIS 10 on Server 2016

I have several sites in IIS. eg

testone.myhome.local

testtwo.myhome.local

I wanted to create a new site, so I added the DNS A record to the zone file for myhome.local and reloaded.
Went to explorer and created a new directory under inetpub/wwwroot called testwp.
Went to IIS and created a new site testwp, pointed it to the directory

Put a simple index.htm in the directory. Setup the bindings to be just port 80 and point to testwp.myhome.local

Now if I go to testwp.myhome.local on the server browser I actually end up at testone.myhome.local

I can not see anything in the log files as to why this site is redirecting.
I don't have any URL rewite.

I have done something wrong but just do not know where. any help?

Thanks

Comment: Can you show us a screenshot of the sites in IIS Manager and a screenshot of the Bindings dialog box for both sites ?

Comment: https://docs.jexusmanager.com/tutorials/binding-diagnostics.html Run some reports on the site bindings and the details should be clear.

Answer (score 1):

If you have multiple sites on port 80, you need to add host headers to each site to enable IIS to forward the request to the correct site, otherwise it will go to the first site listening on the port.